# Pass variable to embeded "For Loop" in SH script

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh

I have an SH script in FreeBSD that I am having issues passing the Variable "count" to a "For Loop".

If I add the

```
count=1
```

after the line

```
for d in $list; do
```

then it works but i need the variable set before this "for loop". The "count=2" prevents the "IF statement" from running a second time while completing the "for d in $list."

I assume this has something to do with local/global variable settings. But I tried several combinations without success.

```
function(){

for i in $data; do
    check=0
    count=1

    [ script lines removed (N/A) ]

    if [ "$check" == "0" ]; then

            [ script lines removed (N/A) ]

            for d in $list; do

                    if  [ "$VAR" == "ABC" ]; then
                            :
                    else

                            if [ "$count" == "1" ]; then

                                   [ script lines removed (N/A) ]
                                   [ THIS "IF" SECTION NEEDS TO RUN ONCE ONLY ! ]

                                    count=2
                            else
                                    :
                            fi
                    fi
            done
    else
            :
    fi
done

}
```

Comment: I have always used a tab for the indents? Is that not the correct way? Also, I tried your script but added another for loop and it worked. But It still doesnt work in my script. I also tried the "-eq 1"

Comment: Using `[ comment ]` makes it impossible to cut-n-paste the example and run it.  Try `# lines removed (N/A)`.

Comment: So you want the `if` section to run at most once for each iteration of the for loop, or just once in total?

Comment: @William, Yes the "If section" needs to run once per iteration of the "for d in $list". See my Answer below. I used the count variable twice and when I utilized "pcount" instead of "count", the script worked. So the "count=1" didn't hold for some reason?  Sorry about the "#" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution - My issue was that I used the same variable name at the top of this script.

```
count=$(cat $data | wc -l)
echo "Found count [ $count ]"
count=1
```

So, my solution was to change the variable name used by the "IF Statement"

"count" to "pcount"

---

```
count=$(cat $data | wc -l)
echo "Found count [ $count ]"
pcount=1
```

I don't understand why re-setting the second count=1, didn't work?

Comment: because the first loop set it back to 1 on every next iteration ?

Comment: @pawel7318, The "If Section" needs to run once only per iteration of the "for d in $list". So the First loop resets it so the next iteration will also run that once. But utilizing the "count" variable, the "If Section" never runs. So setting it as a unique var name "pcount" fixed the issue. Why, I dont know?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

list="foo bar baz"
count=1

for d in $list; do
  if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Tada"
    count=2
  fi
  echo $d
done
```

so where's the issue now ? I have no FreeBSD to check it there, so tell me if it works for you or not.